# STM32F407 Heating up, the decoupling capacitors showing short to ground with multimeter but microcontroller seems working fine

Tags: stm32, heat, short-circuit, decoupling-capacitor, high-current

I have an stm32f407 which was running okay for like a month. but now i am seeing that whenever I connect power supply the current consumption is very high and the MCU is heating up a lot. The decoupling capacitors on the Vdd pins show short to ground with multimeter. I removed 3 of them and checked them with multimeter but they were okay so I placed them back now. Should I go on and remove the rest of the decoupling capacitors and test one by one or the problem is coming from somewhere else? I have a power supply which provides regulated 3.3V and is very reliable.

**Also for information**, this PCB has two sources of power inputs, one is from 12 volt power supply and the other one is from 5V USB. I have two buck converters on this custom PCB and I recently found out that the 5V buck converter has no reverse polarity protection and because of that whenever I connected the USB power and didn't connect the power supply there was this chattering noise coming from the PCB, what I did was that I separated the 5V USB from the 5V buck's output with a knife. And then the high frequency noise disappeared. To remove the possibility that my power circuit may be bad I have disconnected both the buck converters. And connected a 3.3V powersupply directly on the 3.3V trace. So right now I have only two sensors connected to the MCU one is ICM42688 and another one is MS5611. And both works as required and not heating up (I can't feel it with the finger test).

So now I think I have narrowed down the problem to the MCU and the decoupling capacitors, either the MCU is bad or one of the capacitor has gone bad because of that reverse polarity on the buck converter.

Is there anyone who has any experience and can guide me? should I remove the other capacitors as well and check one by one or is there anything else that can be done?

Schematics and PCB layout:
[image]

I removed the traces in pink and placed 3.3V power on the point in green.

[image]

[image]

[image]

this is how the VBUS and the PA9 pins are connected. the VBUS goes nowhere else than lighting up the LED and the PA9 pin. And I have checked just now the PA9 pin is not working. but I still am confused that why it got damaged.

Comment: If it's the MCU that's heating up then it's 99.99% certain that it's the MCU that's bad (not the decoupling caps).

Comment: It may be that a lot of current is passing through the MCU. It may be shorted inside it or some external device on IO pins pushes a lot of current into MCU or draws a lot of current out of MCU.

Comment: It is also possible that one of the cap may be bad and that's causing a lot of current to flow from VDD pins and that's why it heating up, right? 

Also the capacitors are SMD 0402 package so I tried putting finger on them but dont know if the heat comes from MCU or capacitor because they are placed very near to MCU. I think I need a thermal camera. Also if it was an internal short that would cause the MCU to not work properly right?

Comment: how would the decoupling caps draw current through the MCU? ... how do you know that the MCU is `working properly`?

Comment: @MirHamza No, it's not possible that a bad decoupling cap would cause a lot of current to flow from the VDD pins of the uC, causing it to heat up.  A bad cap could draw current from the supply, causing the cap to heat up.

Comment: There's only one case where current could flow *from* the VDD pins of the MCU... if you have signal voltage applied when the power isn't turned on.  And doing that could permanently damage the MCU in various ways.  But even if there's damage, the current will stop flowing out (backwards) when the power supply is turned on and VDD is the highest voltage on the chip.

Comment: Mir, that STM32F407 may still be OK, but latched-up. If peripheral chips are powered with alternate supply, and can be powered-up *before* the microcontroller (even for a moment), latch-up is possible. Proper power-supply-sequencing might solve the problem. If microcontroller has become a heater, the problem is there - not capacitors. However, capacitor charging time might affect power-up timing, and therefore affect power-supply-sequencing.

Comment: jsotola
I know because I have programmed it and also debugged the code. And sensor readings are coming out as required, when I move the sensors around the datachanges accordingly.

Comment: Pretty good chance it's the chip. If those tiny caps (and fairly far from the chip) were getting hot enough to heat the chip they'd probably show some visual indication (turning dark, smoking etc.)

Comment: @BenVoigt thank you for commenting. I think that might be the reason. because I have a USB line and the VBUS connects directly to PA9 which is the VBUS pin on MCU. And this VBUS line does not power the MCU but the power comes from the Debugger USB line. And I think I may have connected the USB cable without connecting the debugger cable before hand and that might have damaged the pin.

Comment: The PA9 pin is 5V-tolerant, the "absolute maximum ratings" says that a 5V-tolerant pin should be no higher than VDD+4.0V.  When the power's off, that's a limit of 4.0V which VBUS very likely exceeds.  Definitely a pit of failure, that -- in the next design iteration some protection diode might be desirable.

Comment: I have added some more screenshots if that helps in identfying the issue.

Comment: Are you using the USB connector in OTG (both host and peripheral)?  If not, the datasheet recommends not connecting PA9 to VBUS.  See Figure 93.

Comment: The new information that PA9 isn't working does seem to confirm that the failure came from connecting 5V at VBUS with no power at VDD.  The circuitry for that pin is damaged and probably the source of heat.  If you remove 5V from PA9 the rest of the chip may keep working; the longer you let it overheat the higher chances that the damage will spread.

Comment: this is my reference design https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/layouts_and_diagrams/schematic_pack/group1/0f/91/8b/39/b3/78/4d/c4/MB997-F407VGT6-B02_Schematic/files/MB997-F407VGT6-B02_Schematic.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.MB997-F407VGT6-B02_Schematic.pdf.

I don't intend to use it both as device and host but I added it anyways. The difference in my design and this reference is that since the EMI filter and ESD protection for the USB was not available at the time of manufacturing and I didn't have time to design again for a different protection scheme I chose to leave it.

Comment: I have still a little confusion that since in this Discovery board design they have the same PA9 connected to VBUS. that means the discovery board will damage if the USB is connected without connecting anyother power source to MCU before hand?

Comment: possibly, but discovery boards usualy has option to power MCU from the all USB ports including this one, so as soon as you connect 5V to PA9 at the same time the regulator will ramp up to make valid VDD.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have PA9 connected to VBUS. VBUS is usually 5V, that means the protection diodes will be turning on and sinking a lot of current from VBUS. You need a resistor at minimum. The ports on a STM32 are 5V tolerant, but that doesn't mean they won't sink a lot of current from a power supply rail.